# tqdm_notebook in Jupyter Notebook prints out plain text instead of showing the progress bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I'm using tqdm_notebook to show progress bars for training loops and long calculations in a pytorch program. It was working fine until it wasn't. Only thing I can think of that may have messed with it is trying to install jupyter-nbextensions for code folding. I couldn't get the nbextensions or the code folding to work properly, so I have removed it.

But now tqdm_notebook progress bar no longer functions correctly. This is the output I get when trying to use it.

[image]

Any ideas on what's going wrong? I've looked all over the place and couldn't find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and have been struggling for days. Finally I found `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` which saves my day and makes `tqdm_notebook` to show the progress bar as normal.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I managed to get it to work again but I was so frustrated at that point, I don't remember what I did to fix it! From what I could recall, I had to go into the conda environment I had installed jupyter in, and delete all json files related to `nbextension`. Then, I edited the `notebook.json` file to remove any references to `nbextension`. Give this a go if nothing else works, but make sure you have a back up.